# Selecting a range of columns using Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a many-column DF from which I need to process various ranges of columns.

In Pandas I could use an expression along the lines of : df.loc[:, 'first_name': 'last_name'] to obtain the required columns between the two end-points. Is there an equivalent in Polars which does not involve listing all the numerous column names in each required range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `df.columns` is just a list you can use the `.index` method to find their locations. Accomplishing this via the eager `[]` API or the `.select` interface can be done as follows:

```py
import polars as pl

def inclusive(target, a, b):
    start, stop = target.columns.index(a), target.columns.index(b)
    return pl.col(target.columns[start:stop+1])


df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date':        ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'],
    'first_name':  ['Alice',      'Bob'       ],
    'middle_name': [None,         'Edward'    ],
    'last_name':   ['Smith',      'Jones'     ],
    'standing':    ['good',       'bad'],
})

print(
    df[:, 'first_name':'last_name'], # eager [] selection
    # shape: (2, 3)
    # ┌────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
    # │ first_name ┆ middle_name ┆ last_name │
    # │ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---       │
    # │ str        ┆ str         ┆ str       │
    # ╞════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╡
    # │ Alice      ┆ null        ┆ Smith     │
    # │ Bob        ┆ Edward      ┆ Jones     │
    # └────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘

    df.select(inclusive(df, 'first_name', 'last_name')),
    # shape: (2, 3)
    # ┌────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
    # │ first_name ┆ middle_name ┆ last_name │
    # │ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---       │
    # │ str        ┆ str         ┆ str       │
    # ╞════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╡
    # │ Alice      ┆ null        ┆ Smith     │
    # │ Bob        ┆ Edward      ┆ Jones     │
    # └────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘


    sep='\n\n',
)
```

Comment: I don't understand `inclusive` and Polars gives `NameError: name 'inclusive' is not defined`

Comment: Did you also copy over the function `inclusive` that is at the top of my snippet?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I did not see code had been scrolled down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the columns using:

```
my_columns = df.columns
```

Then you use regular slicing to get the ranges yo want, say `my_columns[2:5]`, or rather in your case (simplified):

```
col_start = my_columns.index("first_name")
col_end = my_columns.index("last_name")
cols_to_process = my_columns[col_start:col_end]
```